# phpMyAdmin Error - SQL query

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

A newbie to phyMyAdmin, while importing a sql zip file i get the following error message:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_easycontactforms_acl` (`id`, `objtype`, `method`, `name`, `role`) VALUES
(928, 'CustomFormEntryFiles', 'new', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(929, 'Tasks', 'viewDetailed', 'main', 'Owner'),
(930, 'ContactField2', 'show', 'main', 'Owner'),
(931, 'TaskTypes', 'show', 'main', 'Owner'),
(932, 'ContactField1', 'view', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(933, 'OrderFiles', 'viewDetailed', 'detailedMain', 'SuperAdmin'),
(934, 'Products', 'new', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(935, 'Files', 'upload', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(936, 'OrderField1', 'view', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(937, 'ContactField1', 'show', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(938, 'CustomFormFields', 'fixOrder', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(939, 'DashBoardView', 'getDashboardAPIText', 'main', 'Owner'),
(940, 'CustomFormEntryStatistics', 'dismissPointer', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(941, 'OrderField1', 'show', 'main', 'SuperAdmin'),
(942, 'Users', 'show', 'main', 'Owner'),
(943, 'CustomFormFields', 'addCustomField', 'main', 'Owner'),
(944, 'OrderStatuses', 'view'[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '928' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

what i should be doing? Kindly someone point me this newbie in the right direction.

Thanks
Amarnath

Comment: This sounds like the very first record in your `INSERT` is violating a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea there is constraint issue.It give error because during insertion there is multiple entry found for id 928 and you give primary/unique key to that column or may be some column has uniquekey constraint and query try to insert duplicate entry(Same value for that column). So, just check all columns indexing (unique key).